# Image gallery ( images/videos thumbnails with top two horizontal lines)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a design like below: 
[image]

So far, I have done with gallery but now stuck how I can add top two lines using css/html. Please suggest how I can add these lines on top.

my html/css:

```css
.gallery-images img{
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 250px; 
}

.gallery-images{
 padding: 8px;
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
 margin: 0;
}   

.gallery-content{
 margin: 15px 0; 
}
.gallery-content p{
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 0; 
}

.gallery-content span{
 color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<section class="inner-bemployee-wrap clearfix">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                   <div class="thumbnail gallery-images">
                     <img class="img-responsive" src="images/corporate-news.png" />
                     
                   </div>
                   <div class="gallery-content">
                     <p>Album Name</p>
                     <span>15 Photos</span>
                   </div>
                 </div>

               </section>
```

I have used this soudo css:

```css
.gallery-images:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    top: -8px;
    border-top: 3px solid #D09A77;
}
```

Which is showing line on top, but now problem is in mobile/tabular these lines are not 100% fitted according images. How can I restrict lines according to images while expand/stretch on different devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waqas, i think that can be done by adding just two more divs right above your  `<div class="thumbnail gallery-images">` .

Try below code.

```
<div class="first-line"></div>
              <div class="second-line"></div>



.first-line{
 height: 2px;
width: 80%;
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
padding-bottom: 4px;
margin: 0 auto;}

.second-line{
 height: 2px;
width: 90%;
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
padding-bottom: 4px;
margin: 0 auto;}
```

Hope it will help.